# Check permissions of default_role for a text_channel with discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

Using the discord.py library, is it possible to check if the @everyone role has send_message permissions in a given channel within the server? My goal is to avoid 're-opening' a channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is simple, just check the Permissions for the `everyone` role.

```py
everyone_role = guild.roles[0] #ctx.guild in commands and message.guild in on_message

if everyone_role.permissions.send_messages:
    #everyone can send messages generally
    # checking if overwrites exist for the everyone role
    everyone = [e for e in channel.changed_roles if role.position == 0]
    if everyone:
        if everyone.permissions.send_messages:
               #everyone can send message in this channel
        else:
               #they can't
```

Note: everyone is the lowest role in the hierarchy order and has position 0 and index 0 in role lists.

### References:

- [changed_roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel%20role#discord.abc.GuildChannel.changed_roles)
- [Permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role%20permissions#discord.Permissions)
- [guild.roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20roles#discord.Guild.roles)